# No signature of method error after upgrading job-dsl plugin from 1.50 to 1.72

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a `jenkins` job that uses `job-dsl` plugin. With plugin `version 1.50` everything works fine. After upgrading to plugin `version 1.72` the job execution reported the following errors.

> Processing DSL script jobs/custom_xyz.groovy ERROR: (BaseTests.groovy,
>   line xxx) No signature of method:
>   javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.ScmContext.xyzPluginRepoBlock() is
>   applicable for argument types: () values: [] Finished: FAILURE

Have tried the same code with `job-dsl` plugin `version 1.50`. It completed without error.

```
package lib

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.Folder
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.Job
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.ScmContext
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.PublisherContext
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext

import static JenkinsUtils.getOrDefault

public class BaseTests {

    // Credential ID in Jenkins credential store
    .
    .
    .

    def context
    .
    .
    .

    def XYZPluginRepoBlock = { ScmContext context ->
        context.with {
            git {
                branch pluginBranch()
                remote {
                    url pluginRepo()
                    credentials 'jenkins-cred'
                }
                extensions {
                    relativeTargetDirectory 'XYZ'
                    wipeOutWorkspace
                    clean
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def extras = { Job context -> }

    public setupDeployJob(TemplateName, TemplatePath, nextJob = 'Undeploy') {
        context.with {
            def workdir = "$TemplatePath"
            job("${folderName()}/${TemplateName}${BASE_DEPLOY_JOB_NAME}") {
                jobDescription = "Deploys the $TemplateName Template using the XYZ Manager."
                description(jobDescription)

                if (!isMaster())
                    extras(delegate)

                environmentVariables {
                    env('DP', "${folderName()}-${TemplateName}${BASE_DEPLOY_JOB_NAME}-\$BUILD_NUMBER")
                }

                wrappers {
                    preBuildCleanup {
                        includePattern('results/**')
                        includePattern('outputs.properties')
                    }
                    credentialsBinding {
                        usernamePassword("xyz_USERNAME", "xyz_PASSWORD", xyzCred())
                    }
                }
                multiscm {
                    xyzPluginRepoBlock delegate
                    if (isMaster()) {
                        git {
                            branch 'master'
                            remote {
                                url 'http://<coderepourl>'
                            }
                            extensions {
                                wipeOutWorkspace
                                clean
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public setupUndeploy(jobTitle = 'Undeploy', nextJob = null) {
    .
    .
    .
    }
}
```

Help needed to understand what the error means and how to resolve it.

Comment: You need to post a complete but minimal script that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?  Has the wrappers method been removed?  What is the replacement?